# MantisBT - Assign Issue to Group

Tags: debugging, workflow, issue-tracking, mantis

Sometimes in development, we need a group not individual to work on a task. So, how can I assign an issue reported in MantisBT to a group, not individual?

Answer (score 0):

By default the concept of User Group is not yet available in MantisBT. However there are plugins available, but those are not recommended as they require core code customizations.